# Verifying Authentication to a Telnet Session in Python

Tags: python, authentication, telnet, verification, cisco

I am trying to telnet into a Cisco Switch and run a couple of commands on it.  I am able to check if the host doesn't exist, not sure how to check if the username or password is correct.  This is what I got so far(This is part of my class)

```
def login(self):
    if self.user_name and self.password: 
        try:
            self.connection=telnetlib.Telnet(self.telnet_host)
            try:
                self.connection.read_until('sername:',1)
                self.connection.write(self.user_name+'\r\n')
                self.connection.read_until('assword:',1)
                self.connection.write(self.password+'\r\n')
                self.connection.read_until(self.prompt,1)
                print "Connected"
                self.loggedON=True
            except EOFError:
                print "Authentication to "+ self.telnet_host+" failed.\n"
                return
        except: 
            print "Can't connect to "+self.telnet_host+"\n"
            return
    else:
        if not self.user_name:
            self.user_name=raw_input("Username: ")
            self.login()
        else:
            self.password=raw_input("Password: ")
            self.login()
```

It will still say it is connected even if the wrong password or username.

Comment: Telnet... plain text authentication... 'nuff said.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but have you looked into SNMP? There is a good chance that using SNMP is much better solution.

Comment: And to answer you question: You must read what you get after sending the password and compare it to the message you get when you are logged in. I don't know if `read_until` has a timeout but if it doesn't your program will wait forever or until the switch terminates the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try [Exscript](https://github.com/knipknap/exscript/wiki/Python-API-Tutorial):

```
from Exscript.util.start import quickstart

def do_something(conn):
    conn.autoinit()
    conn.execute('show version')

quickstart('telnet://localhost', do_something)
```

The *quickstart()* function asks the user for username and password (use *start()* if that is not what you want). Login failure (and other errors) are handeled automatically. You may also want to look at [Exscript.util.start](http://knipknap.github.com/exscript/api/Exscript.util.start-module.html).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't have a blanket try/except block like that. Catch exceptions more narrowly. Also, as others have commented, you might consider SNMP.

Having said that, if you push ahead with Telnet, you might as well just reuse someone else's code. I found [this](http://www.goldb.org/telnetpython.html) for example with a simple Google search.